# In Super Mario Bros which button is used to run and to jump?

Tags: nes, super-mario-bros

In Super Mario Bros which button is used to run and to jump? I'm asking this question because I heard that most of games use the button A to jump. If my memory is good it is the button B that is used to jump in Super Mario Bross Game. But on the NES gamepad the button A is on the right and the button B on the left, right?

Comment: Well, it IS a genuine question; albeit a silly one.

Comment: It's technically a valid question, but it shows absolutely no research effort, which is the very first thing listed in the downvote tooltip. It probably won't get closed, but you shouldn't be surprised by downvotes, either. I have a difficult time believing that you couldn't find the answer when a Google search for "super mario bros controls" returns several accurate results in the first page alone.

Comment: I downvoted your question because I don't view it as useful. Unless you're playing Super Mario Brothers then this question doesn't serve any purpose. If you are playing Mario Brothers then there's no way you wouldn't be able to quickly figure out how to run and jump unless you just gave up without even picking up the controller.

Comment: I asked this question because I use to play this game and I'm mapping my gamepad for another game. I also ask the question because it is common now to put the jump button of any platform on the bottom one. I just realize that Super Mario Boss, the platformer by default, the one that everybody knows, do not use this new standard of jump button on the bottom button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>A</kbd> is used to jump. I most of the game <kbd>A</kbd> is used to jump.
<kbd>B</kbd> is used to run.

On the NES gamepad (and gamecube) the buttons <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> are reversed compared to the Xbox 360, Xbox One, and other conventional gamepad. Then in term of position in most of games you jump with the bottom left button, in Mario Bros you jump with the upper right button.

Comment: You know, at one time the NES *was* the 'conventional' gamepad

Comment: Note the switch also decided to invers button A and B. This is also true for menu Ok and back button.

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>A</kbd> is used to jump or swim up, whereas <kbd>B</kbd> is used to shoot a flame or run. Have a look at the [current world record speedrun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wR8x5b_ExM) to see it in action.

If you're actually asking *how* one would use both buttons, I can at least tell you how I played it. I placed my thumb on the <kbd>B</kbd> and would press <kbd>A</kbd> with the joint (similar to the player in the video):

[image: thumb image - haha. sorry. don't mind me.]

That's actually the way for most of the NES jump 'n runs.

Source: I own a NES and the game ;).

Comment: Alternatively, for some other games I had rather unique setup. For track&field, where one needed to mash A as fast as possible, I used to hold the controller between my palms, with thumbs extended, so that when i moved my hands alternately back and forth my thumbs would *both* hit A, alternately.

For F15 Strike Eagle, i used both controllers on the floor in front of me, so that i could use them both for their various functions (one for flying and one for weapons, if i remember correctly). For most other games, the above picture worked well.

Comment: Why not use two fingers for buttons A and B?

Comment: @Rodrigo Take a modern controller, e.g. PS4 or XB One controller. Just pick it up and hold in both hands. You'll notice that almost *all* buttons and sticks except the shoulder buttons are meant to be controlled with your thumbs, whereas your other digits mostly stabilize the controller. The same holds for early gamepads: you only use the thumbs to control and let the controller rest on your digits. If you've used your fingers for A and B, you'd have to stabilize the controller in some other way (e.g. lay it flat) or hold it entirely in your left hand (which is uncomfortable).

Comment: I have never played this new videogames (PS4 or XB1). I used to play NES, Sega Genesis and SNES, all using different fingers for buttons, and had no problem stabilizing the controller. I think that most pro gamers would agree that using different fingers for different buttons give us much more control.